# 3D Map mapper that takes a 2D image as an input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

Does any have an idea on how to create similar shapes programmatically.   What I want to do is to create levels from a 2D images. Please check the below image to get a better idea. 
What you see in the images is not a mesh, its a lot of small cubes layered out together to create that images.
Thank you for your help.[image: Example]

Comment: This is not a programming question this is a search in the asset store. It could be phrased as a programming question if you were interested in building this functionality yourself but otherwise GameDev SE or Unity forums are your best bet. ps. Extruding simple 2D images into 3D isn't difficult. I personally would usually write this kind of thing myself, just to have precise control over the behavior.

Comment: This question, as is, is not on topic at GameDev SE either.

Comment: The idea seems actually quite simple: Take the Image/Texture, reduce the resolution to a certain level, Get the Pixel Color data, iterate through the pixels and spawn cubes with according color. If you try this and post your code as example we sure can help to figure out **coding related** issues.